# distributive law of set in this book seems incomplete

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I saw this equation from a Chinese math book:

$$ (A\setminus B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \setminus (B \cap C) $$

IMO, the equation can be more general like this, which is actually the law of commutation.

$$ (A\setminus B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \setminus B$$

Am I correct?

And even more, I think this equation is also correct:

$$ (A\setminus B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \setminus (A \cap B)$$

Comment: Does $A \setminus B \cap C$ denote $(A \setminus B) \cap C$ or $A \setminus (B \cap C)$?

Comment: @Brian Oh, I thought they always calculate from left to right... I just added some parentheses for clarification.

Comment: You can draw venn diagrams and see if you get the same result

Comment: that's what I did, and I cannot find a counter example... but I'm still not sure, why there is no such a law like I wrote.

Comment: It is not that there is no such law (and indeed there is), rather it is that it is not a *rule of distribution*, that is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is true that $(A\setminus B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\setminus B$.  As you say, by commutation: $(A\cap B^\complement)\cap C=(A\cap C)\cap B^\complement$ .

Likewise that $(A\setminus B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\setminus (A\cap B)$ and $(A\setminus B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\setminus (A\cap B\cap C)$.   Both are easily proven, or visually demonstrated by a Venn Diagram.

However, if the book is listing *rules for distribution*, well, these are not examples of the distribution of $\cap$ over $\setminus~$, where as $(A\setminus B)\color{navy}{\cap C}=(A\color{navy}{\cap C})\setminus (B\color{navy}{\cap C})$ is.

Comment: $ A \setminus B = A \cap B^C$ inspired me like the light house.